# Как добавить в регулярное выражение пробел

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть вот такое регулярное выражение.

```
/^\p{L}{1,64}$/u;
```

И сюда нужно добавить возможность ставить 0 или больше пробелов. И лучше, чтобы проверяла также, чтобы после пробелов было слово или буква

Comment: Может, `/^(?=.{1,64}$)\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)*$/u`?

Comment: да, сработало. спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
/^(?=.{1,64}$)\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)*$/u
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/cLse6A/1).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?=.{1,64}$)` - проверка на длину строки, в ней должно быть от 1 до 64 знаков, отличных от символов перевода строки
- `\p{L}+` - 1 и более букв
- `(?:\s+\p{L}+)*` - 0 и более повторов

  - `\s+` - 1+ пробельных символов
  - `\p{L}+` - 1 и более букв
- `$` - конец строки

Comment: как еще добавить сюда возможность написать - и .

Comment: `/^(?=.{1,64}$)\p{L}+(?:[\s.-]+\p{L}+)*$/u`?